# Script to send keys to a specific process that has duplicate name

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, sendkeys

I'm new here so I apologize for any errors in my question.

I'm writing a powershell script to uninstall a program, I need it to send keys to that program to click through the parts asking for user inputs. Problem is that my script calls to a process that has a duplicate name, it cant differentiate between the two. Only difference is how much memory it is using. Is there a way to select the process based on how much memory it is taking up? I appreciate any help.

[image: snippet of task manager]

```
$a = Get-Process | ?{$_.name -eq 'setup'}
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.appactivate($a.Id)
Start-Sleep 5
$wshell.sendkeys('~',10)
$wshell.sendkeys('~',5)
```

Comment: Is that the *details*, or *process* tab?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala its the details tab, the process tab shows: programname.exe(32-bit) (2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to note up front:

- Trying to automate applications *by simulated user input*, such as by sending keystrokes, is inherently brittle, and should only be used as a last resort.

  - In the case at hand, see if `setup.exe` supports parameters that obviate the need for interactive responses.
- The [`.SendKeys()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//8c6yea83(v=vs.85)) has no documented *second* parameter - what do you think that does?

---

To get the process of interest, try the following:

```sh
$a = Get-Process setup |
       Sort-Object -Descending WorkingSet64 |
         Select-Object -First 1
```

For additional robustness, consider filtering the set of candidate processes by their `.StartTime` property.